# HTML Parsing into Column in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in the table in html format,i needs to parse that xml to get the data in it as column.

eg :

```
DECLARE @Html   varchar(7000)   =   '

<tr>
<td rowspan = 3 align=''center''><==slno==></td>
<td rowspan = 3 align=''center''>May 31 2018  4:16PM</td>
<td rowspan = 3 align=''center''>Initiated</td>
<td rowspan = 3 align=''center''>bm.rini2</td>
<td rowspan = 3 align=''center''><==ApprovedBy==></td>
<td rowspan = 3 align=''center''></td>
<td align=''center''>Role Code</td>
<td align=''center''>-</td>
<td align=''center''>testrrr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=''center''>Role Name</td>
<td align=''center''>-</td>
<td align=''center''>testrrr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=''center''>Show Masked Card No.</td>
<td align=''center''>No</td>
<td align=''center''>New</td>
</tr>

'
```

My required Output will be like this :

```
     --------------------------------------------------
        Field Name              Old Value   New Value
     --------------------------------------------------

       Role Code                -           testrrr

       Role Name                testrrr     testrrr

       Show Masked Card No.      No         New

     --------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that in DB?I would suggest do that in AP side.

Comment: I wants the result in DB.can't use AP side.

Comment: You could **only** do this with Dynamic SQL, as the columns aren't static. It's not going to be pretty, or easy (imo). Honestly, I agree, T-SQL is not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a solution.
First you need to alter your html input so that it has a format we can work with to parse into a table. The code below uses substring and replace to convert the html into a CSV. Obviously it relies on the html sticking to a format:

```
Set @html = substring(@html,charindex('<td align=''center''>',@html,0),4000)
Set @html = replace(@html, '<tr>','')
Set @html = replace(@html,'</tr>','#')
Set @html = replace(@html,'<td align=''center''>','''')
Set @html = replace(@html,'</td>','"',')
Set @html = replace(@html,',
#','#')
```

Now we have @html as a CSV file using ',' as a field delimiter " as a text delimiter and # as a row delimiter.

I then have this natty function which can convert a CSV in a variable into a table. Note that this function relies on [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). Note that the function will dynamically create column names if none are supplied. You could pre-pend the final @html variable with a header row however. :-

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCSVasTable]
(

    @fileentry varchar(200),
    @headerrow int,
    @datarow int,
    @rowdelimiter varchar(10),
    @fielddelimiter varchar(10),
    @textdelimiter varchar(10)
)


AS

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myrows') IS NOT NULL    DROP TABLE #myrows
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myrowsfixed') IS NOT NULL    DROP TABLE #myrowsfixed


create table #myrows
(rowid int,rowstring varchar(max))

create table #myrowsfixed
(rowid int, rowstring varchar(max))

declare @mycsv as varchar(max)
set @mycsv=@fileentry

insert into #myrows
select * from [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](@mycsv,@rowdelimiter)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32000)

IF (select count(*) from #myrows) =1 
BEGIN

Select 'Row delimiter could not be found in file'
RETURN

END


;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT x.rowstring as n,x.rowid as nid, s.[itemnumber] as [Index], s = REPLACE(s.item, @fielddelimiter, 
    CASE s.[itemnumber]%2 WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE @fielddelimiter END)
  FROM #myrows AS x 
  CROSS APPLY  dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(x.rowstring, @textdelimiter)  AS s
)

insert into #myrowsfixed
SELECT x.nid,fixed = (SELECT x2.s 
  FROM x AS x2 
  WHERE x2.nid = x.nid
  ORDER BY [Index]
  FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'varchar(max)')
FROM x
GROUP BY x.nid;


declare @myheader as table
(rowid int, colname varchar(500))

insert into @myheader
select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K((select rowstring from #myrowsfixed where rowid=@headerrow),@fielddelimiter)
where item is not null

select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K((select rowstring from #myrowsfixed where rowid=2),',')

IF (select count(*) from @myheader)=0
BEGIN
insert into @myheader
select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K((select rowstring from #myrowsfixed where rowid=2),',')
where item is not null
END

declare @minrow int,@maxrow int,@script varchar(max), @mycol varchar(500)
set @minrow=1
set @maxrow = (select max(rowid) from @myheader)

set @script='Select '



WHILE @minrow<=@maxrow
BEGIN

IF @headerrow=1 set @mycol=(select colname from @myheader where rowid=@minrow) else set @mycol='COL' +  cast(@minrow as varchar)
set @script=@script + @mycol + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN ca.ItemNumber = ' +cast(@minrow as varchar)+' THEN Item ELSE '''' END),'

set @minrow=@minrow+1

END
print @script
set @script=left(@script,len(@script)-1) + 'FROM #myrowsfixed csv
  CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(csv.rowstring,''' + @fielddelimiter+''') Ca 
  WHERE rowid>='+cast(@datarow as varchar)+' 
  GROUP BY csv.rowid
;'

print(@script)
exec(@script)
```